# How to get the object button belongs?

Tags: java, android, listview, object, button

I have a ListView of custom objects. This object contains a TextView with a name `text_name`, a TextView with a value `text_value` and a Button `button_add` that adds a value in a EditText `field_value`, it belongs the object, to the `text_value`. This is the object class:

```
package rafaelmarinho.pague10;

import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class Element
{
    private String _name;
    private int _value;
    public Element(String name, int value)
    {
        _name=name;
        _value=value;
    }
    public void setValue(int value)
    {
        _value=value;
    }
    public void percentIncrease()
    {
        _value=(int)ceil(_value * 1.1);
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return _name;
    }
    public int getValue()
    {
        return _value;
    }
}
```

And this is object's custom adapter:

```
   class elementAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Element>
{
    public elementAdapter()
    {
        super (MainActivity.this, R.layout.item_layout, elements);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if(view == null)
        {
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_layout,parent,false);
        }

        Element currentElement = elements.get(position);

        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_name);
        name.setText(currentElement.getName());
        TextView value = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_value);
        value.setText(String.valueOf(currentElement.getValue()));

        return view;
    }
}
```

I have a function that is called when the button is pressed, but any of my tries to make it add the value in `field_value` to `text_value` worked. So, what should I do?

Comment: move your button event handler into the adapter.

Comment: May I move it into `getView` or outside it?